# How to detect browser Refresh or Close?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

In my application I want user to take an single signin. when he is leaving the application. As name explains, It should happen only when user closes current browser tab or browser window or browser referesh button. Its possible using JavaScript OnUnload event. But the problem is that this event occurs on

1. close of browser tab
2. close of browser window
3. click of any internal page link(i.e anchors, form buttons and buttons events)
4. click of browser's Refresh button
5. click of browser's Back/Forward button

I have handled first 3 cases but not able to detect browser Refresh and Back/Forward button click.
Has anybody of you implemented such functionality, Please help me??

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO, please read where to add [urgent](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: use a session to store the page they land on, detect if its the same

Answer (score 5):

A better way to know that the page is actually reloaded is user the navigator object that is supported by most of the new version browser. It uses the HTML 5 navigation time API.

```js
//check for navigation time API support
if (window.performance) {
  console.info("window.performance work's fine on this browser");
}
  if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
    console.info( "This page is reloaded" );
  } else {
    console.info( "This page is not reloaded");
  }
```

source : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API

**Answered By** : [Rahul Jain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5809610/rahul-jain)

Comment: So I thought until i read carefully 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigation

"how the navigation to the current document was done" (not how navigating from the current document)

Comment: I just found out about this wonderful solution and I'd have used it... if it was not deprecated :(

Comment: @MassimilianoCaniparoli **Update on the above:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming/type

Comment: Use it like this: `if (performance.getEntriesByType('navigation')[0].type != 'navigate') {}`

Answer (score 3):

Use ajax on events. use (async javascript request)

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
       $(window).bind('unload', function(){
         $.ajax({
           type: "get",
           async: false,
           url: "URL CONTROLLER/FUNCTION"
         });               
    });
</script>
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
           $(window).bind('unload', function(){
                        $.ajax({
                        type: "get",
                        async: false,
                        url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>finance_cron/log_cron/<?php echo $this->session->userdata('user_login_event_id2'); ?>"
                  });
                 
        });
</script>